# Pass NSString in Xcode settings

Tags: ios, compiler-construction, nsstring

I would like to know if it's possible to retrieve in my code different NSString declared in my Xcode scheme or project setting ...
Would be useful if a client have to request some secret URL. He just have to modify the schemes or settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is <strike>environment variables.</strike> a preprocessor definition. You can set them in the preprocessor macros of the Xcode build settings.

Take a look here as well: [Adding a Preprocessor Definition via a Xcode Scheme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8319325/adding-a-preprocessor-definition-via-a-xcode-scheme)

Comment: Environment variables haven't got anything to do with preprocessor definitions.