# Find the Xcode Build scheme name at run time

Tags: ios, xcode

Is there a way to find out the Scheme used at the run time ?

May be there is a better way to do this, I'm trying to set the Access Environment (Production vs Development) by using the Scheme name.

Currently I use `#define ENV @"PROD"` in `App-Prefix.pch` file to do this, but there is a chance to miss this when sending pkg to apple for review :(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When running an app on the simulator or on your device, the `DEBUG` variable is set, allowing you to use it from your code:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
    // Something
#else
    // Something else
#endif
```

You can see this variable from your target's build settings:

[image]

As soon as the `Run` configuration is set on `Debug` (Product -> Scheme -> Edit Scheme), this variable will be set:

[image]

Comment: Yeah, doing this using the **Build Configuration** is likely better than inferring it via the Scheme, since build configuration also affects lots of other build settings.

Answer (score 40):

I searched far and wide for an answer to this because I really don't like the idea of creating extra Targets nor extra Configuration sets. Both of those options just create a huge Configuration synchronization problem.

So, after hacking Xcode for a couple of hours, this is what I came up with:

**Step 1**: Add the key "SchemeName" to your Info.plist with type string.

**Step 2**: Edit your default scheme and on Build -> Pre-actions add a new Run Script with the following:

```
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :SchemeName \"$SCHEME_NAME\"" "$PROJECT_DIR/$INFOPLIST_FILE"
```

Make sure and select a target from under "Provide build settings from".

**Step 3**: Now *duplicate* that scheme as many times as you like (Manage Schemes... -> Select existing scheme -> Click gear icon -> Duplicate) For instance, you can create Development, Staging, Production, App Store, etc. Don't forget to click "shared" if you want these schemes carried around in version control.

**Step 4**: In the code, you can retrieve the value like this:

```
NSString *schemeName = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] valueForKey:@"SchemeName"];
```

Or in Swift:

```
let schemeName = Bundle.main.infoDictionary?["SchemeName"] as? String ?? ""
```

Now, the code can configure itself correctly at runtime. No nasty preprocessor macros to deal with and no brittle configuration mess to maintain.

UPDATE: According to the comments below, `$PROJECT_DIR` might need to be removed depending on where your Info.plist is located in your project.

Comment: This is great and works! I set only the 'SchemeName' key in info.plist, and when I run the build the value is set. Here's my question: where does $SCHEME_NAME come from? I've searched the documentation for XCode environment variables (and the internet) and can't find any reference to it whatsoever.

Comment: Before I got it working, I had the Run Script command echo out all environment variables (Xcode sets a bunch before executing the script). I just then searched through it until I found a likely suspect.

Comment: And in fact, if I recall correctly, this env var is only set in the scheme related Pre/Post actions. I don't think it is set in a normal Run Script in the Build Phases.

Comment: This is awesome. Thank you for sharing this.

Comment: For swift 4.2 use: Bundle.main.infoDictionary?["SchemeName"] as? String ?? ""

Comment: in XCode 11.4 I have to remove the `$PROJECT_DIR/` part in the script, so it becomes: `/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :SchemeName \"$SCHEME_NAME\"" "$INFOPLIST_FILE"`

Comment: I'm currently running Xcode 12.5 and your original pre-action run script is the correct one. It doesn't matter which Xcode version you're using, but rather where your Info.plist file is placed within your project directory.

Comment: The problem with this method is that it actually changes the plist file. This file in most of the is tracked when using a repository. Hence when changing a scheme the change might be pushed to the remote repository if not discarding it before.