# Modify App Transport Security based on Scheme

Tags: ios, xcode, info.plist

How do I modify App Transport Security settings in the Info.plist file based on the scheme?

For example, I want to turn off ATS in my debug/enterprise schemes whereas I need ATS turned on in release scheme. How do I do this?

Comment: Posible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27548496/how-can-i-change-plist-entries-based-on-my-scheme

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new user defined setting in Build Settings using + button beside the search bar, customize it based on your scheme and use that key in the Info.plist.