# iOS - Initialise WebEngage SDK Conditionally with different Accounts Ids

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, iphone, webengage

I am in need of Initialising WebEngage SDK based on some conditions.

```
if condition {
//initialise with `X` Account ID
} else {
//initialise with `Y` Account ID
}
```

But as per [WebEnage-Documentation](https://docs.webengage.com/docs/ios-getting-started) there is no method for initialising SDK with accountId.
we just call below code in our AppDelegate's **didFinishLaunchingWithOptions** method.

> WebEngage.sharedInstance().application(application,
> didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)

and it initialise the SDK by reading account id from **info.plist** file.
I tried updating **Info.plist** at run time but that didn't work.
I am looking for the right approach to do it.

Comment: What's `condition` Is it a Swift Flag? If so, you could have different plist for each scheme? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27548496/how-can-i-change-plist-entries-based-on-my-scheme Else, maybe an env file, and filling the plist values with them with a script on build?

Comment: @Larme he is looking for run time solution.

Comment: If by "account", you mean the `WEGLicenseCode`, then there is a method available apparently to do so: `-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions setLicenseCode:(NSString *)licenseCode;`

Answer (score 0):

In WebEngage v6.0.0 a new initialising method is introduced that can have licenseCode as parameter.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication?, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [AnyHashable : Any]?, notificationDelegate: WEGInAppNotificationProtocol?, autoRegister apnRegister: Bool, setLicenseCode licenseCode: String?) -> Bool
```

I initialises SDK with help of above method in  AppDelegate's **didFinishLaunchingWithOptions** method.

```
if staging {
   WebEngage.sharedInstance().application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions, setLicenseCode: "xyz")
} else {
   WebEngage.sharedInstance().application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions, setLicenseCode: "abc")
}
```