# release-debug configuration in React-Native

Tags: ios, configuration, react-native, release

Currently in React-Native, according to [the documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device-ios.html#building-your-app-for-production), to build your iOS app for production, you need to :

- change your scheme to `Release`
- change your `AppDelegate.m` to load the correct bundle
- change your `Info.pList` for ATS

This is a strong violation of [12 factor config recommandation](http://12factor.net/config), and it leads to mistakes being made in a continuous integration process.

RN does not provide either out-of-the box strategies to know the configuration environment in the JS code, leading to the existence of the package [`react-native-config`](https://github.com/luggg/react-native-config), which does a great job already, but is not perfect [(Xcode is not fully supported)](https://github.com/luggg/react-native-config#ios).

Why is it so? Is it because there are actually so few RN app in production today that nobody cares about this? Can we do better than `react-native-config` so that steps listed above are not required? I would like a command line that archives my app in the same way that I can run `cd android && ./gradlew assembleRelease`, without changing anything to my config.

**EDIT:**

[Fastlane](https://fastlane.tools) makes deployment a lot easier through its `gym` command (thank you Daniel Basedow). Apparently, the philosophy of Xcode is to call environments "schemes", only you cannot store variables in them, or know which scheme you're running in your code... Anyway, David K. Hess found [a great way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15857285/find-the-xcode-build-scheme-name-at-run-time/26433618#26433618) to export your scheme name in your `Info.plist`, and then in your Objective C code, which means I'm now able to chose my bundle according to the current scheme, and not touch my code.

Here is my code:

`NSString *schemeName = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] valueForKey:@"SchemeName"];
if ([schemeName isEqualToString:@"scheme1"]) {
  jsCodeLocation = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost:8081/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true"];
} else if ([schemeName isEqualToString:@"scheme2"]) {
  jsCodeLocation = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://<my_local_ip_address>:8081/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true"];
} else if ([schemeName isEqualToString:@"scheme3"]) {
  jsCodeLocation = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"main" withExtension:@"jsbundle"];
}`

Now my problem is : I also want to know which scheme I'm running in my JS code. `react-native-config`'s way is self-described as hacky, and overly complicated considering the fact the information is already in my Objective C code. Is there a way to bridge this information to my JS code?

Only knowing which scheme I'm running is not as good as being able to set environment variables, but at least I'll be able to switch between environments only by changing my scheme.

**EDIT 2:**

I managed to export my scheme to my JS code. I created a cocoa touch class with the following code:

```
//  RNScheme.h

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "RCTBridgeModule.h"

@interface RNScheme : NSObject <RCTBridgeModule>

@end




//  RNScheme.m

#import "RNScheme.h"

@interface RNScheme()

@end

@implementation RNScheme
{

}

RCT_EXPORT_MODULE()

- (NSDictionary *)constantsToExport
{
  NSString *schemeName = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] valueForKey:@"SchemeName"];
  NSLog(@"%@", schemeName);
  return @{
           @"scheme_name": schemeName,
           };
}

@end
```

and then in my JS code:

```
import {NativeModules} from 'react-native'
let scheme = NativeModules.RNScheme.scheme_name
```

**EDIT 3:**

There is actually another way than using schemes. You can create new "configurations" ("Release" and "Debug" are called configurations) with the following steps (thanks [CodePush](https://github.com/Microsoft/react-native-code-push#codepushgetupdatemetadata)):

1. Open up your Xcode project and select your project in the Project
   navigator window
2. Ensure the project node is selected, as opposed to one of your
   targets
3. Select the Info tab
4. Click the + button within the Configurations section and select
   which configuration you want to duplicate

[image: Xcode configuration screenshot]

Then you can define keys with different values according to your configuration.

5. Select your app target
6. Chose Build Settings
7. Go to User-Defined section (at the bottom of the scroll area)
8. You can define constants with a different value according to your configuration (for instance `API_ENDPOINT`)

You can then reference this value in your `Info.plist` file :

9. Open your `Info.plist` file
10. Create a new value and give it a name (`ApiEndpoint`)
11. Give it the value `$(API_ENDPOINT)` or whatever name you gave to your constant

Now you can reference this value in your code using the code I gave you in my second edit to this question.

You can create one scheme per configuration to switch quickly from one to the other, or change the build configuration each time (option click on the run button).

Comment: Do you happen to have an example for Android as well :)

Comment: `fastlane deploy` works nicely for android. You can add config files using react-native-config.
A nice alternative is expo.io : all the native code is abstracted for you, all the configuration is centralized and available using a single file for both Android and iOS.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your AppDelegate you can use the correct bundle like this

```
#ifdef DEBUG
  jsCodeLocation = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost:8081/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true"];
#else
  jsCodeLocation = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"main" withExtension:@"jsbundle"];
#endif
```

When you do a release build, the DEBUG flag is not set. You can also use different files as your Info.plist depending on build type. There will probably be situations where you want an Xcode debug build with a production JS bundle or vice versa. In that case you need to touch code.

Building ios apps from command line can be a bit tricky. The problems you're describing are not specific to react-native but the Xcode build system. If you haven't already, check out [fastlane](https://fastlane.tools/) especially the gym command. It is much simpler than using xcodebuild directly.

But you still have to define your schemes.

Comment: `DEBUG` flag is not enough for me. According to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26433618/3995091) though, I can get access to the current scheme. Fastlane looks amazing, I will give it a try.

Comment: Even though this answer did not answer the question, I found this answer very helpful :)