# Can you get Android/iOS app build variant from within Kotlin-Native?

Tags: android, ios, kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-native

From within my Kotlin-Native shared code I need to get the build variant of the app running it - for both Android and iOS.

Is it possible and how can I get it?

Assuming in `commonMain` I'll have `expect val buildVar: String`,
then how would I get the respective build variants within the `androidMain` and `iosMain` main directories? `actual val buildVar = ...???`

Comment: Seems like you can do something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23431354/how-to-get-the-build-variant-at-runtime-in-android-studio) in Android part, and like [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26433618/11533773) for iOS.

Comment: @ArtyomDegtyarev thanks, but those work natively - I'm looking to do it via kotlin-native. I'm not sure if it is possible, but hoping someone has an answer out there. 

Like something similar to `import platform.UIKit.UIDevice

actual fun platformName(): String {
  return UIDevice.currentDevice.systemVersion
}`
to get the iOS device's system version.

Comment: I think you can `import platform.Foundation.NSBundle` and go with a solution above. About android - in the question it is unclear are you targeting `android()` or `androidNativeArm32/64`. For just `android()`, the first link seems totally applicable.

Comment: Thanks! - for iOS that was helpful. Got an implementation which in theory seems to work, but will post a solution when I get a chance to run it properly. I'm targeting android() but not having any success in trying to access the buildConfig from Kotlin-Native.

Comment: See also:https://github.com/yshrsmz/BuildKonfig