# separate source files for separate schemes in XCode 4

Tags: ios, xcode, simulator

I have some source files:

```
iosA.m
iosB.m
x86ABC.m
```

which perform similar tasks differently on IOS and simulator, respectively. How do i handle this in XCode 4? I would have thought it would be a case of specifying the schemes for a specific file (the default being that a file is used for all schemes) but if this is the case i cannot find how to set it.

thanks!

Comment: Dustin's answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8319325/adding-a-preprocessor-definition-via-a-xcode-scheme

Comment: urgh.. the files are quite different due to the underlying platforms and i don't want to put a bunch of preprocessor junk in them or go through non-obvious hoops. I was considering building separate static libs, one per platform, but it seemed like work.

Comment: tried creating a stub file that would conditionally include the architecture-specific .m files, but it doesn't seem like objective-c allows this based on the parser errors.

Comment: worked around it by building a separate lib for each architecture