# xcconfig: Different preprocessor macros for Debug/Release

Tags: xcode, preprocessor, xcconfig

I have created and applied a simple .xcconfig file containing

```
GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS[config=Debug] = FOODEBUG
GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS[config=Release] = FOORELEASE
```

and main.cpp containing

```
#include <iostream>

// This warning IS shown
#if DEBUG
#warning DEBUG is set to 1
#endif

// This warning IS NOT shown
#ifdef FOODEBUG
#warning FOODEBUG is set
#endif

// This warning IS NOT shown
#ifdef FOORELEASE
#warning FOORELEASE is set
#endif

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    // insert code here...
    std::cout << "Hello, World!\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Now I'm wondering why in main.cpp, neither FOODEBUG nor FOORELEASE are defined ??!

As expected, the build settings show the two lines of my .xcconfig file ("Any Architecture | Any SDK"), but they are not actually used.

[image: Xcode screenshot]

How could I achieve that?

Answer (score 4):

If you have a preprocessor macro you need to give it a value to be able to use it as you do, see a screenshot of one of my project setups as a sample:

[image]

The reason why you can access DEBUG is difference is the different behaviour between `#if` and `#ifdef`.
`#if` will be true when the macro exists, `#ifdef` if it has a non zero value. I suggest to always assign the value one to be save, because I'm not sure the above is true for all compiler versions.

**UPDATE:**
Did not know that before, but it seems `config=Debug` does not work. Although the macros get visible in the settings, they do not inherit up.
What does work is 2 xcconfig files similar to this:

Release.xcconfig:

```
GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS = $(inherited) FOORELEASE=1
```

Debug.xcconfig

```
#include "Release.xcconfig"
GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS = $(inherited) FOODEBUG=1
```

Please also see James Moores answer here: [How to append values in xcconfig variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393987/how-to-append-values-in-xcconfig-variables)

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: Sorry for being unclear, please see my edited answer.
I'm not talking about changing the macros, but assigning a non zero value. Hope that helps

Comment: Still I don't get what this has to do with my question. The difference is very clear to me, but none of the macros is defined *at all* by Xcode. Having a value or not shouldn't matter here.

Comment: Maybe I'm just not getting you right ...
It does make a difference if you have a value, try setting it in the settings window.
If for some reason you need to do that in the xcconfig file try:
GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS[config=Debug] = "FOODEBUG=1"
(not sure about the quotes)

Comment: I did that and it doesn't work. If you could provide a working example, the bounty is yours :)

Comment: It looks like you can not achieve that with a single config file, you will need to have separate files for debug and release. I updated the answer with an example

Comment: "#if will be true when the macro exists, #ifdef if it has a non zero value." - this is the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define preprocessor macro this way:

```
GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS[config=Debug] = $(inherited) FOODEBUG=1
GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS[config=Release] = $(inherited) FOORELEASE=1
```

For more details see the [official documentaton](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/adding-a-build-configuration-file-to-your-project/).